# Example to create android application with rails turbolink

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I have to build an android hybrid application with rails using `turbolink` but could not find any simple example, i have no experience with java, but a good experience with rails.I found one [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shplrnG48s0&t=1211s) but not of much help.
Please suggest and share the links to create some basic example apps. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be downloadable from the play store and not just a phone browser app, my best advice is probably to spin up a new React Native app that manages your front-end views, and makes API requests to your backend Rails app. Your Rails app would not deliver views to your React Native, it would deliver JSON. React Native apps can be released to both the iOS and Android app stores.

There are tons of good tutorials to achieve that. Hope it helps.

Comment: purpose of using turbolink is to reduce our effort in maintaining separate codebase for web,android and ios, i don't want too use React Native .